# How to replace the data type "undefined" with a text (string)? (weather API project)

Tags: javascript, weather-api

I am creating a project that displays the current weather of an area by name search. I fetch the API data from open weather: https://openweathermap.org/current?fbclid=IwAR1SVc9zn9uXaZWLmJA9lYEeZvUc1s_kR68RFadWuIwd8yBjIyJ7zsVMKkE

I have added all the parametres of the API to my code, but if you search some areas, they don't "return" all the weather API parameters. For example, when I search my city's weather at the moment, the parameter " Atmospheric pressure on the sea level" is displaying "undefined" because as Open Weather stated:

[image]

Because of that, I don't want the final project to display:

> Atmospheric pressure on the sea level: undefined

I want it to return something among the lines of:

> Atmospheric pressure on the sea level: not found

As you can see, the data type undefined is replaced with a string.

However, I have found a function here on this site that replaces undefined with "0" and it seems to work because it is marked as "solution". Due to my lack of knowledge tho, I cant get it to work.
The code I have found:

```
    function replaceUndefined(displayWeather){
  if(typeof(displayWeather) === "undefined"){
      return "0"; // return 0 as replace, and end function execution
  } 
  return displayWeather; // if the above state is false, functions continues and return original value
};
```

Now, here is my whole JAVASCRIPT code:

```js
let weather = {
  apiKey: "χχχχχχχχχχχχχχχ",
  fetchWeather: function (city) {
    fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        city +
        "&units=metric&lang=el&appid=" +
        this.apiKey
    )
  
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          alert("No weather found.");
          throw new Error("No weather found.");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
  },
  
  displayWeather: function (data) {
    const { name } = data;
    const { lon } = data.coord;
    const { lat } = data.coord;
    const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
    const { temp, humidity } = data.main;
    const {temp_min} = data.main;
    const {temp_max} = data.main;
    const { pressure } = data.main;
    const { sea_level } = data.main;
    const { speed } = data.wind;
    const { deg } = data.wind;
    const { sunrise } = data.sys;
    const { sunset } = data.sys;
    //getting the data from the JSON API file.

  

    document.querySelector(".city").innerText = "Καιρός: " + name;
    // (".city") is the class name from the DIV in HTML file.
    document.querySelector(".lon").innerText = "Γεωγραφικό μήκος (longitude): " + lon;
    document.querySelector(".lat").innerText = "Γεωγραφικό πλάτος (latitude): " + lat;
    document.querySelector(".icon").src =
      "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
    document.querySelector(".description").innerText = description;
    document.querySelector(".temp").innerText = temp + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".temp_min").innerText = "Ελάχιστη θερμοκρασία (αυτην την στιγμή): " + temp_min + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".temp_max").innerText = "Μέγιστη θερμοκρασία (αυτην την στιγμή): " + temp_max + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText =
      "Υγρασία: " + humidity + "%";
    document.querySelector(".pressure").innerText = "Πιέση: " + pressure;
    document.querySelector(".sea-pressure").innerText = "Ατμοσφαιρική πίεση στο επίπεδο της θάλασσας: " + sea_level;
    document.querySelector(".wind").innerText =
      "Ταχύτητα αέρα: " + speed + " km/h";
    document.querySelector(".wind-deg").innerText = "Κατεύθυνση του αέρα (degrees): " + deg;
    document.querySelector(".sunrise").innerText = "Ανατολή Ήλιου: " + window.moment(sunrise * 1000).format('HH:mm a');
    document.querySelector(".sunset").innerText = "Δύση Ήλιου: " + window.moment(sunset * 1000).format('HH:mm a');
    document.querySelector(".weather").classList.remove("loading");
    document.body.style.backgroundImage =
      "url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?')";
  },

  
  search: function () {
    this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
  },
};

document.querySelector(".search button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  weather.search();
});

document
  .querySelector(".search-bar")
  .addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
      weather.search();
    }
  });

weather.fetchWeather("London");
//Loads weather of London when the page opens
```

(some texts in the code are in greek because I want the text that is displayed on the page, to be in that language)

Thank you. Please I need solution.

Comment: first of all - remove your api key from here.... replace it with some string. second, you can use `someVar || someOtherString` so if the first one will be undefined it'll use the second value

Comment: Oh, is there a reason why I should not include my api key? I am a begginer in all this

Comment: @BegCoder if you were using a paid service then people can use that service for free using your api key

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".sea-pressure").innerText = "Ατμοσφαιρική πίεση στο επίπεδο της θάλασσας: " + sea_level || 'not found';
```

Or just for hide all the line if data doesn't exist

```
    if(seal_level){
       document.querySelector(".sea-pressure").innerText = "Ατμοσφαιρική πίεση στο επίπεδο της θάλασσας: " + sea_level;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer but  None of these 2 seem to work...